# I somehow broke Anti-Aliasing in Visual Studio 2022. Now all labels and UI elements are jagged despite ClearType enabled

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, winforms, antialiasing

### EDIT: Found a Workaround

Please scroll to the end of the issue to see.

---

For some reason, after working on another project, everything I add in new projects doesn't have anti-aliasing applied. It's as if ClearType is being ignored.

I know this was working before because every project up until now had perfectly functioning anti-aliasing. I also have a prior project that anti-aliases fine when testing.

Here's what's happening:

### Before:

---

[image]

### After:

---

[image]

Notice how one of the labels doesn't even show up! I'm completely confused and have no idea how to fix this.

Does anyone here know what I broke and how to fix it?

Thanks so very greatly.

### Edit 1

---

I've narrowed things down a bit. I am using Ironman Software's PowerShell Pro Tools, and there is an option to switch between `Windows PowerShell (Integrated x64)` and `Powershell 7 (x64)`.

When I switch to `Windows PowerShell (Integrated x64)`, the Anti-Aliasing problem goes away and everything looks as it's supposed to.

If I switch to `PowerShell 7 (x64)`, the horrible anti-aliasing comes back and everything looks terrible again.

I'd really like to stick with Powershell 7, but the anti-aliasing problem is a non-starter for me. Does anyone know why changing PowerShell versions would cause anti-aliasing to break in Visual Studio Community?

Thanks for any help.

### Edit: Workaround

So after experimenting a bit with the form, if you set `FlatStyle` to `System` instead of `Standard` (The default), then your labels or components will anti-alias correctly.

If you use Flat/Popup/Standard instead, the anti-aliasing will break once again. So, it's not a solution to this bug, but at least a kind-of viable workaround.

Comment: Change the Font of everything to `Segoe UI`, 9pt. What do you see?

Comment: @Jimi it still looks jagged. I made some progress though. When I switch my PowerShell settings in the `Options > PowerShell Tools` to `Windows PowerShell (Integrated x64)`, the anti-aliasing goes back to normal and looks good. 

But if I switch to `PowerShell 7 (x64)`, the anti-aliasing reverts back to looking horrible.

I don't know why this is happening, but I do need to use PowerShell 7 for this project. I've reached out to the guys at IronMan Software for help to see if they can help narrow down this problem since I think this is a bug related to PowerShell Pro Tools.

Comment: Is this exclusive to winforms?

Comment: Not sure. There is no option to create a WPF app with PowerShell so I can't really test.